# specific UI is not generated using item-right in ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

I am new to `Ionic 2` and facing problem to generate specific UI. I am getting [this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV0n0.png) but what I want is [this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OSzz.png).

I want the status to be displayed above the date. Here is my code:

```html
<ion-content class="SalesOrderLogin">
  <ion-list>
    <button dark ion-item detail-none *ngFor="let fod of foods" (click)='orderSelected("order")'>
      <div *ngFor="let food of foods; let isEven=even">
        <h6 *ngIf="isEven">{{food.Property}}</h6>
      </div>
      <div item-right *ngFor="let food of foods; let isOdd=odd">
        <h6 *ngIf="isOdd">{{food.Property}}</h6>
      </div>
    </button>

  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Thanks in advance.